# Беспорядочная загрузка файлов на сервер в Codeignither

Tags: php, codeigniter

Есть четыре input для выбора файла, и загрузки его на сервер.

```
<input type="file" name="file[0]" size="20" class="file_upload"/>
<input type="file" name="file[1]" size="20" class="file_upload" style="margin-left: 50px;"/>
<br /><br />
<input type="file" name="file[2]" size="20" class="file_upload"/>
<input type="file" name="file[3]" size="20" class="file_upload" style="margin-left: 50px;"/>
```

Загружаются все нормально, но проблема в том, что я в первый input выбираю один файл, и так же остальные в четкой последовательности, а он загружает в своей последовательности. Как решить? Ниже код загрузчика. Использую родную библиотеку codeignither.

```
$config['upload_path'] = './images/hf';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '25000';
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);

$temp_files = $_FILES;
$count = count ($_FILES['file']['name']);

for ($i=0; $i<=$count-1; $i++)
    {
        $_FILES['file'] = array (
        'name'=>$temp_files['file']['name'][$i],
        'type'=>$temp_files['file']['type'][$i],
        'tmp_name'=>$temp_files['file']['tmp_name'][$i],
        'error'=>$temp_files['file']['error'][$i],
        'size'=>$temp_files['file']['size'][$i]);
        $this->upload->do_upload('file');
        $tmp_data = $this->upload->data();

        if ($i==0){
            $gallery['cover']=1;
        } else {
            $gallery['cover']=0;
        }
        $gallery['sort'] = $i+1;
        $gallery['img']= $tmp_data['file_name'];
        $gallery['id_hf']=$id_hf;
        if (!empty($gallery['img'])){
           $this->admin_model->add_gallery($gallery);
        } 
        $files_data[$i]['data'] = $tmp_data['full_path'];

    }
```

p.s. Var Dump

```
array(5) { ["name"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(12) "hospital.jpg" [1]=> string(25) "1438104491_image00002.jpg" [2]=> string(10) "bolnic.jpg" [3]=> string(7) "med.jpg" } ["type"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" [1]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" [2]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" [3]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(14) "/tmp/phppE4Hw8" [1]=> string(14) "/tmp/phphyPJe6" [2]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpaKiNW3" [3]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpNVbSE1" } ["error"]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(0) [2]=> int(0) [3]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(8751) [1]=> int(24022) [2]=> int(41313) [3]=> int(68671) } }
```

Comment: тут проблема не в загрузке кажется, а на самом цикле. Можете показать результат команды `var_dump($_FILES['file']);`

Comment: еще один момент, вы учитываете размер файлов? может из за размера он не успевает загрузить??

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev обновил вопрос

Comment: @duddeniska, а зачем вы меняете содержимое `$_FILES`?

Comment: Без него не пашет(